# How can I group items close to each other without knowing the distribution?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm preparing some data about sold apartment prices for regression analysis. One category is what street the houses are on, but some streets have very different areas, so I want to make a category with the combination of construction year and street name.

```
Broadway 1910
Broadway 2001
```

Forexample my challenge is that sometimes the construction spans over several two years. The data is from Sweden, known for huge centralized housing projects. I would like to group these houses together into a period somehow. This is my current code. I know it's not very efficient, but it will only run once on a not huge dataset.

```
(async () =>{
    let client;
    try {
        client = await MongoClient;
        let collection = client.db("booliscraper").collection("sold");
        let docs = await collection.find();
        await docs.forEach((sale) => {
            sale.street = sale.location.address.streetAddress.split(/[0-9]/)[0] + sale.location.namedAreas[0]
            sale.streetYear = sale.street+" "+sale.constructionYear

            log(sale);
            collection.replaceOne({_id: ObjectId(sale._id)}, doc)
        });


    client.close(); 

  } catch(err) {
    log(err)
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly said, your current code is inefficient when it comes to dealing with huge datasets so instead of making several calls to the server to do `replaceOne` within your `forEach` loop, you can create an aggregate query that computes the category fields you want with the $group pipeline and push the documents that fall into those categories into an array that you will later use to do a bulk update.

For the bulk update you can use [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany) method on the collection that will have multiple updateMany operations.

The following operation shows the intuition above in practice:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        let client = await MongoClient;
        let collection = client.db("booliscraper").collection("sold");
        let pipeline = [
            { '$group': { 
                '_id': {
                    'street': { 
                        '$concat': [
                            { 
                                '$arrayElemAt': [
                                    { '$split': [
                                        '$location.address.streetAddress', 
                                        /[0-9]/
                                    ] },
                                    0
                                ]
                            }, 
                            {  '$arrayElemAt': [ '$location.namedAreas', 0 ] },
                        ] 
                    },
                    'streetYear': { '$concat': ['$street', ' ', '$constructionYear']  }
                },
                'ids': { '$push': '$_id' }
            } }
        ]
        let docs = await collection.aggregate(pipeline);
        let ops = docs.map(({ _id, ids }) => ({
            'updateMany': {
                'filter': { '_id': { '$in': ids } },
                'update': { '$set': { 
                    'street': _id.street, 'streetYear': _id.streetYear 
                } }
            }
        }));
        let result = await collection.bulkWrite(ops);

        log(result)

        client.close()

    } catch(err) {
        log(err)
    }
})()
```

Comment: This is really useful information, but not at all an answer to my question :). (The reason I use the method I do is because i'm not very fluent in mongodb and the data manipulation is actually suppose to be performed on a json-object that is fetched from a api and then stored to the database. I don't want to write duplicate code that might also risk working in another way)

Comment: Can you possibly edit your question to include some sample documents from your collection, the json-object that is fetched from a api and your expected results? So in essence, would like to know your typical `input -> output` so that I can correctly deduce the operations required in mongodb to give the desired/expected output.